# Extract numbers with AHK

Tags: regex, extract, autohotkey

The code below is supposed to extract numbers from the selected text and to display them in a message box, but nothing is extracted and displayed. Any idea? Thanks

```
  ^!1::
    ; Get the currently selected text
    Clipboard := ""
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait, 2

    ; Store the copied text
    CopiedText := Clipboard

    ; Extract numbers using regular expression
    regex := "\b\d+\b"
    numbers := []
    Loop, {
        match := RegExMatch(CopiedText, regex, number)
        if (!match)
            break
        numbers.push(number)
        CopiedText := SubStr(CopiedText, match.Pos + match.Len)
    }

    ; Display the extracted numbers
    MsgBox % numbers.Join(",")
return
```

Comment: Without further inspection of a code, I can tell you right away the there is no such method as `.Join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex removes all non digit characters from clipboard:

```
numbers := RegExReplace(clipboard, "m)\D+")
MsgBox "%numbers%"
```

**EDIT:**

To separate the extracted numbers with a comma, try this:

```
numbers := RegExReplace(clipboard, "m)\D+") ; remove all non digit characters from clipboard
Loop, Parse, numbers                        ; retrieve each number from clipboard, one at a time
    numbers_separated .= A_LoopField ","    ; add the retrieved number plus comma to a new variable
numbers_separated := Trim(numbers_separated, ", `r`n") ; remove leading and trailing commas, CRs and LFs 
MsgBox "%numbers_separated%"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested code. The thing is that I need the numbers as they are found in the sentence separated with a comma.